# Default mail registry

Tags: group-policy, windows-registry, windows-8.1, microsoft-office-2013

I'm deploying Win 8.1 via. SCCM with Office 2013 pre installed.
I got an issue where even though Outlook 2013 is the default mail.
the specific value mail:to (opening a direct mail link) .. attempts to open in the build-in mail App.

I want that to open in Outlook, and I dont want to have to change that on every machine
in 'default programs'. So can you help me find the registry for 'default mail:to' .. so I can change it from mail to Outlook.
And do a Group policy?

thx

Comment: Does this happen before you have sysprepped, or only after?

Comment: honestly havent checked that yet.. because.

in office 2010, I had the base files and used the OCT Tool to customize.. a lot of stuff like 'trusted locations' etc.

but with my Office365, I use a click-to-run applikation, and Microsoft tells me changes must happen via. Group policy, which honestly sucks, cause there were plenty changes I made.

if you know how I can modify the installation proper, before syspreppen, I would be happy about that

Comment: Have you tried deploying office click to run post sysprep?

Answer (score 0):

from the top of my head, have you created/edited your Office .INI file? there is config file that comes with MS Office installations wherein registry settings and such can be configured and gets pushed to workstations at the same time as Office is installed.

Comment: with office 365, 2013?

I use the offline deployment Tool.. gives me a setup.exe, and a configuration.xml
in the configuration.xml I tell what office version, a few basic stuff.. 32bit

I couldn't find anything about me being able to change specific settings right away there.

**Also actually what I do, is I deploy to to a 'base image' that I sysprep and capture, so in that way Office 2013, is already installed in the Windows image, as the only app.
Could I make changes into office, on the base installation, and keep those settings? even when I sysprep it? in your experience**

Comment: yes Office 2013. i guess your problem stems from the source machine. you have to first make sure the default mailto: is set correcly before imaging (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command) them.